# How to get pact verification results across all the provider versions against a new consumer contract?

Tags: testing, producer-consumer, pact, contract

Lets say I have provider version 1 deployed in prod and version 2(latest code in main/master branch) deployed in staging. Now consumer has updated his side of contract and when the provider pipeline is triggered and the pact verification results are published, its published against version 2 of the provider and there is no entry in the pact broker for provider version 1 against the new version of the consumer contract.

We are trying to follow the diamond approach suggested by pactflow where we do can i deploy for both staging and prod before merging the code to main branch. And since the above behavior gives NOK for can i deploy in prod, I can't merge the code to main branch.

4 years back a team in our company has explored pact broker and documented how it works. In that documentation I see that when the pact verification results are published, the latest consumer contract had results against both version of the provider.

Is there a setting or something which need to use or change which will give me pact verification results against all versions of the provider and not just for the latest version of the provider?

Is there a setting or something which need to use or change which will give me pact verification results against all versions of the provider and not just for the latest version of the provider?